# Cannot figure out where to put ORDER BY

Tags: php, sql-server

I know where not to put it, at least.

I inherited this project from my predecessor. I know very little about PHP and SQL Server, but here we are. The first while loop contains the problem. I need to ORDER BY UserType, but obviously it is just ordering one entry every time because of where it is in the while loop. The result is meant to be that the results are shown with one user type first in alphabetical order, then the second user type in alphabetical order.

Google, and searching here, have only been moderately enlightening because most examples don't seem quite this complicated. It may be something simple, but I don't see it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$sql = "SELECT UserID FROM vw_AgentService WHERE StateID = ".$state.
"AND OrgID = ".$org.
"AND ServiceID = ".$service; //JOIN
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $sqlb = "SELECT * FROM vw_UserInfo WHERE UserId = ".$row["UserID"].
    " AND (UserType = 1 OR UserType = 2) ORDER BY UserType DESC, UserLastName"; //Herein lies the problem
    $stmtb = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlb);
    if ($stmtb === false) {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));

    }

    while ($rowb = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmtb, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $sqlc = "SELECT * FROM vw_UserPhotoPath WHERE UserID = ".$row["UserID"];
        $stmtc = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlc);
        if ($stmtc === false) {
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

        while ($rowc = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmtc, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if ($rowc['PhotoFilePath'] === null) {
                echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id=".$rowb["UserID"].
                "\">".
                "<li><img src=\"profile/blank-avatar.png\" width=\"100\" />";
            } else {

                echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id=".$rowb["UserID"].
                "\">".
                "<li><img src=\"http://demo-bc.cmfirsttech.com:8081/".$rowc['PhotoFilePath'].
                "\" width=\"100\" />";
            }

        }

        echo $rowb["UserFirstName"].
        " ".$rowb["UserLastName"].
        "<br/><span class=\"info\">".$rowb["UserTitle"].
        ", ".$rowb["UserCompany"]; // Should the ORDER BY actually go here?
        //.</span></a></li>"; //rm </br>, add ", "


    }

}
```

I've been told that the ORDER BY usually goes at the end, but I am not sure I understand the logic because at that point it is just echoing the data I already have.

Comment: You're right that you wouldn't ORDER BY when you are fetching just one row by UserID. However, the order in which you process UserID's comes from the first SELECT statement (at the top of your code block) and you _can_ use ORDER BY on that query

Comment: You should look at this article before bobby tables makes an unwelcome appearance on your sql server. http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

Comment: I have been advised of the Bobby Tables issue. As of right now, I am meant to get this thing sorted by user type. I have a lot to learn about SQL injection before I can even begin to address that. But thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I understand learning and tackling it in small chunks but I would advise you not to put this code in production until you fix the injection vulnerability. It can be very ugly and incredibly painful to fix if somebody hacks your sql server. Fix the issue at hand but don't forget to also make is secure.

Comment: Noted and logged. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ORDER BY clause should be added to the end of the SQL statement.

Something like this;

```
$sqlc = "SELECT * FROM vw_UserPhotoPath WHERE UserID = ".$row["UserID"] . " ORDER BY UserType";
```

That's assuming UserType is in your source view (vw_UserPhotoPath).

**EDIT 1 - Should have read the question properly**

You actually need your ORDER BY on the very first SQL call, ie;

```
$sql = "SELECT UserID FROM vw_AgentService WHERE StateID = ".$state." AND OrgID = ".$org. "AND ServiceID = ".$service . " ORDER BY UserType";
```

This is because the second query only returns one record.  This first query is what's getting the list so where the order by should be placed.

Comment: This isn't the line of the problem, it happens at line : `$sqlb = "SELECT * FROM vw_UserInfo WHERE UserId = ".$row["UserID"].
    " AND (UserType = 1 OR UserType = 2) ORDER BY UserType DESC, UserLastName"; //Herein lies the problem`

Comment: My apologies, yes, where the ORDER BY is shown is correct.  I've updated my response to reflect this.